# phpMyAdmin shows MySQL returned an empty result set for Variable Declarations

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a SQL query that starts with a SET command to set a variable so I don't have to go find it in the script every time.

```
SET @startdate = '2016-11-01';
SET @enddate = '2016-11-26';
SELECT stuff
FROM table
```

When I run the query via phpMyAdmin I get 3 result sets because it treats the variable SET command as separate queries. (screenshot below)

Down below the first two showing the warning I do get my data just fine.  I'm just trying to figure out how I can not see the first two empty result sets if that's possible.

I don't know if this is a mySQL thing or a phpMyAdmin thing but any help would be great.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Oops I have the same problem!! There has been some change? It worked fine before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a set the variables in a subquery and use cross join with the table to use them.

```
select stuff
from table
cross join (
    select @startdate := '2016-11-01',
        @enddate := '2016-11-26'
    ) t
where date_added between @startdate and @enddate
```